# Fatal error: wp_create_nonce() not defined in script-loader.php

Tags: wordpress, fatal-error

Out of nothing my wp website stopped working.
This is the message I get when I turn the debug on.

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_validate_auth_cookie' not found or invalid function name in /home/u775042855/domains/amosermae.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 288

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_create_nonce() in /home/u775042855/domains/amosermae.com/public_html/wp-includes/script-loader.php:1058 Stack trace: #0 /home/u775042855/domains/amosermae.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(288): wp_default_scripts(Object(WP_Scripts)) #1 /home/u775042855/domains/amosermae.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(312): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #2 /home/u775042855/domains/amosermae.com/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(544): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 /home/u775042855/domains/amosermae.com/public_html/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php(167): do_action_ref_array('wp_default_scri...', Array) #4 /home/u775042855/domains/amosermae.com/public_html/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php(142): WP_Scripts->init() #5 /home/u775042855/domains/amosermae.com/public_html/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php(23): WP_Scripts->__construct() #6 /home/u775042855/domains/amosermae.com/public_html/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php(128): wp_scripts() #7 /home/u775 in /home/u775042855/domains/amosermae.com/public_html/wp-includes/script-loader.php on line 1058
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: what had you done before this?

Comment: No recent core or plugin updates?

Comment: Absolutely nothing, it was fine the last time I checked.

Comment: Reinstalled wordpress and everything is back to normal